# How to I point multiple URLs to the right directory?

Tags: apache, dns, centos

I have a VPS running CentOS 5.  I want to point multiple domains at the same VPS (point them at the same IP), but serve up distinct websites for each domain.

So, the setup I want is like this:

`site1.com`  ---->  127.0.0.1  ----> `/var/www/html/site1.com/`
`site2.com`  ---->  127.0.0.1  ----> `/var/www/html/site2.com/`

I've tried setting up virtual hosts through the CentOS GUI for Apache, but they don't seem to be working.  Only the first virtual host added will work (i.e. If I add `site1.com` first, both domains direct to that site.  If I add `site2.com` first, both domains direct to that site.)

What might I be doing wrong?  Is there an effective step-by-step tutorial for newcomers to get me started?

---

### Update

Please remember, I have little to no experience working with CentOS and Linux ... but I'm learning.

To those who asked to see the directives I'm using, here's what CentOS added to the bottom of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` when I used the built-in Apache GUI:

```
<VirtualHost skylarkapp.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/skylarkapp.com
    <Directory "/var/www/html/skylarkapp.com">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    ServerName skylarkapp.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost eamann.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/eamann
    <Directory "/var/www/html/eamann">
        allow from all
        Options +Indexes
    </Directory>
    ServerName eamann.com
</VirtualHost>
```

At the moment, all traffic to both `skylarkapp.com` and `eamann.com` on this system direct to the content of `/var/www/html/skylarkapp.com`.

Also, I'm using my Windows `hosts` file to manually point `eamann.com` to this server (204.92.23.6) because I'm in the process of migrating a live site.  I want to get things working on the server before I actually move things from one box to another.

Comment: Could you post your VirtualHost directives so we can see them?  That is the preferred solution, ideally we could find the issue with it rather than have you try some less-desirable workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name-based virtual hosts must be turned on explicitly with `NameVirtualHost *:80`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Turns out this was what I needed.  And there was a commented-out line for NameVirtualHost farther up in the configuration file, I just never saw it.  Strange how the UI for Apache in CentOS will allow you to add name-based virtual hosts but won't explicitly turn them on for you ...

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
<VirtualHost eamann.com:80>
```

won't work since eamann.com won't resolve to your CentOS server's IP address (only your Windows machine resolves eamann.com to 204.92.23.6). Try making apache listed on any IP by replacing with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

You probably also want:

```
ServerAlias www.eamann.com
```

to allow visitors to www.eamann.com to see the site as well. Restart apache after making these changes:

```
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Made that attempt ... but it didn't help.  All traffic is still being eaten by the first virtual server (even requests to the bare IP http://204.92.23.6/).

Comment: @EAMann: Did you turn on name-based virtual hosts with `NameVirtualHost *:80` at all? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: @Chris, please post that as an answer.  That helped me solve the problem!